# ¿Cómo solucionar el error de Apps Script en el que se necesita una API?

Tags: javascript, api, google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

estoy trabajando con Apps Script porque quiero desplegar algunos metadatos de un video de YouTube en una hoja de cálculo de SpreadSheets. El código con el que estoy trabajando funciona bien en consola, pero cuando intento usar esa función en la hoja de cálculo, me aparece el siguiente error: GoogleJsonResponseException: API call to youtube.videos.list failed with error: The request is missing a valid API key.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código que estoy usando en el proyecto el siguiente:

```
function tiempo() {
  var stats = YouTube.Videos.list("contentDetails", {id: "BD0Ogjxy8hw"});
  Logger.log(stats.items[0].contentDetails.duration);
}
```

Comment: Necesitas una `API key` valida para usar esa `API` en google `APP Script`

Answer (score 0):

El problema se debe a que estás intentando usar una servicio que requiere autorización en una "custom function" (llamar una función de Google Apps Script en una fórmula de Google Sheets).

Las "custom function" se ejecutan sin pasar las credenciales requeridas, en este caso, por el servicio avanzado YouTube Data. Ref. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions

La solución más sencilla podría ser que en lugar de usar una "custom function"  llames tu función de un menú, botón, diálogo, barra lateral (sidebar) o activador installable (installable trigger). Otra alternativa es que en lugar de usar el servicio avanzado de YouTube data uses el UrlFetch Service para llamar directamente a la API incluyendo las credenciales necesarias.

Comment: Y si, esto tambien es cierto, y es lo mas probable.